# Parallelized access to servomotors in Arduino

Tags: multithreading, arduino, interrupt-handling

I took a quick peek at the Arduino Servo library and it's pretty tough going.  Clearly, it waits when a write command is issued.  The fact that it blocks makes it very slow to combine a servomotor command with other code, or to control multiple servos (for example, a hand with 5 fingers).

One approach would be to have a multithreaded library on the Arduino, but I haven't seen a library with multiple threads on the Arduino.  But to control multiple servos, it would be just as good to have an asynch API that allows us to set n servo requests, then say go and they all go simultaneously.  Is there any such API?  Is there a reason in hardware that this cannot be done?

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading on Arduino is not possible beacause it is not using the same kind of processor you would find in your computer.

Doing multiple things at once is therefore not possible. You could try to mimic the way and operating system works with processes but that won't be easy.

If you need more power and more "intelligence", why not try a raspberry pi?

Comment: This is just silly.  It's a 16Mhz processor, albeit with very small RAM.  Multithreading is possible, just slow and with a tiny stack frame.  However, I mostly wanted the other solution anyway.

Comment: can you be a little more precise on what you call "multithreading" ?